# Evaluate Derivative of Negative Log Likelihood Python

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, derivative, log-likelihood

I am trying to evaluate the derivative of the negative log likelihood functionin python. I am using sympy to compute the derivative however, I receive an error when I try to evaluate it. The example code below attempts to compute this for the lognormal function.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym
from sympy import Product, Function, oo, IndexedBase, diff, Eq, symbols, log, exp
from scipy.stats import lognorm

np.random.seed(seed=111)
test = lognorm.rvs(s=1,loc=2,scale=1,size=1000)

x = IndexedBase('x')
i = symbols('i', positive=True)
n = symbols('n', positive=True)
mx = symbols('mx', positive=True)
sx = symbols('sx', positive=True)

pdf = 1 / (x[i] * sx * sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * exp(-0.5 * ((log(x[i]-mx))**2/(sx)**2))
Log_LL = -log(Product(pdf, (i, 1, n)))

deriv = diff(Log_LL, mx) 
fx = lambdify([x,mx,sx,n],deriv)
fx(test,2,1,len(test))
```

When I evaluate this formula, I receive the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-139-452f00dee1f1> in <module>
      1 fx = lambdify([x,mx,sx,n],deriv)
----> 2 fx(test,2,1,len(test))

<lambdifygenerated-14> in _lambdifygenerated(Dummy_39, mx, sx, n)
      3   # Derivative
      4   # Product
----> 5 -Derivative(Product(0.398942280401433*exp(-0.5*log(-mx + Dummy_39[i])**2/sx**2)/(sx*Dummy_39[i]), (i, 1, n)), mx)/Product(0.398942280401433*exp(-0.5*log(-mx + Dummy_39[i])**2/sx**2)/(sx*Dummy_39[i]), (i, 1, n)))

NameError: name 'Derivative' is not defined
```

I realize that the expression "deriv" contains the derivative operator, but I am simply computing the derivative of a single variable, so I believe sympy should be able to handle this.

I am running sympy 1.7.1, numpy 1.19.2 and scipy 1.5.2

Thank you!

Comment: Before using `lambdify`, look at `deriv`.  `lambdify` is a simple lexical translator, leaving things like `Derivative`, `Product` and `Dummy_39` that aren't meaningful in `numpy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the symbolic sympy and the numeric numpy/scipy don't mix well. It is usually recommended separating them. Also, sympy doesn't like floats as these prevent exact symbolic calculations. Therefore, instead of `np.pi`, sympy's symbolic `pi` is preferred. Also, `0.5` should be replaced by a sympy fraction, for example `S.Half`. (See also [sympy's gotchas](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#evaluating-expressions-with-floats-and-rationals).)

Sympy's derivative doesn't seem to be able to cope with the `Product`. We can try to replace the log of the product by a sum of the logs. `expand_log(..., force=True)` can help with that conversion (`force=True` when sympy isn't sure that the expression is certain to be positive, presumably the `x[i]` could be complex).

When converting to numpy, numpy doesn't like the indexing starting from 1. This can be solved with indexing starting from 0.

```py
from sympy import Product, Sum, IndexedBase, diff, symbols, log, exp, lambdify, sqrt, pi, S, expand_log

x = IndexedBase('x')
i = symbols('i', positive=True)
n = symbols('n', positive=True)
mx = symbols('mx', positive=True)
sx = symbols('sx', positive=True)

pdf = 1 / (x[i] * sx * sqrt(2 * pi)) * exp(-S.Half * ((log(x[i] - mx)) ** 2 / (sx) ** 2))
# Log_LL = -Sum(log(pdf), (i, 0, n - 1))
Log_LL = -log(Product(pdf, (i, 0, n-1)))
Log_LL = expand_log(Log_LL, force=True)

deriv = diff(Log_LL, mx)
fx = lambdify([x, mx, sx, n], deriv)

from scipy.stats import lognorm
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(seed=111)
test = lognorm.rvs(s=1, loc=2, scale=1, size=1000)
fx(test, 2, 1, len(test))
```

This way, sympy manages to calculate the derivative symbolically:

```
 n - 1                 
  ____                 
  ╲                    
   ╲   log(-mx + x[i]) 
    ╲  ────────────────
-   ╱    2             
   ╱   sx ⋅(-mx + x[i])
  ╱                    
  ‾‾‾‾                 
 i = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I know copy-n-paste displays of `sympy` expressions are not optimal, but I like to see them.  It gives readers a clearer idea of what's happening.  Otherwise they have to run the code themselves.  I can do that when reading this on my computer with a `isympy` session handy, but can't when using a tablet or phone.

```
In [164]: pdf
Out[164]: 
                           2             
                   -0.5⋅log (-mx + x[i]) 
                   ──────────────────────
                              2          
                            sx           
0.398942280401433⋅ℯ                      
─────────────────────────────────────────
                 sx⋅x[i]                 

In [165]: Log_LL
Out[165]: 
    ⎛       n                                                  ⎞
    ⎜─┬────────────┬─                                          ⎟
    ⎜ │            │                             2             ⎟
    ⎜ │            │                     -0.5⋅log (-mx + x[i]) ⎟
    ⎜ │            │                     ──────────────────────⎟
    ⎜ │            │                                2          ⎟
-log⎜ │            │                              sx           ⎟
    ⎜ │            │  0.398942280401433⋅ℯ                      ⎟
    ⎜ │            │  ─────────────────────────────────────────⎟
    ⎜ │            │                   sx⋅x[i]                 ⎟
    ⎜ │            │                                           ⎟
    ⎝     i = 1                                                ⎠
```

So the `log` wraps the `Product` (displayed with the big `pi` symbol), but doesn't try to do anything with the inner expressions.

```
In [166]: deriv = diff(Log_LL, mx)

In [167]: deriv
Out[167]: 
    ⎛       n                                                  ⎞ 
    ⎜─┬────────────┬─                                          ⎟ 
    ⎜ │            │                             2             ⎟ 
    ⎜ │            │                     -0.5⋅log (-mx + x[i]) ⎟ 
    ⎜ │            │                     ──────────────────────⎟ 
  ∂ ⎜ │            │                                2          ⎟ 
-───⎜ │            │                              sx           ⎟ 
 ∂mx⎜ │            │  0.398942280401433⋅ℯ                      ⎟ 
    ⎜ │            │  ─────────────────────────────────────────⎟ 
    ⎜ │            │                   sx⋅x[i]                 ⎟ 
    ⎜ │            │                                           ⎟ 
    ⎝     i = 1                                                ⎠ 
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
           n                                                     
    ─┬────────────┬─                                             
     │            │                             2                
     │            │                     -0.5⋅log (-mx + x[i])    
     │            │                     ──────────────────────   
     │            │                                2             
     │            │                              sx              
     │            │  0.398942280401433⋅ℯ                         
     │            │  ─────────────────────────────────────────   
     │            │                   sx⋅x[i]                    
     │            │                                              
         i = 1
```

The `diff` does the `df(x)/dx/x` log differential, but doesn't try to act on the `Product`.

I haven't used `Product` before, or even read its docs, so I don't know if there's a way forcing further evaluation.  Come to think of it, isn't the `diff` of `f1(x)*f2(x)...*fn(x)` rather long and messy?  Something about the product rule for differentiation.

I wonder if setting `n` to be a small number (e.g. 3) rather than a variable would make a difference.

Anyways, there's no point in passing this through `lambdify`.  As the code in the error message shows, `lambdify` doesn't evaluate or clean up sympy, it just makes simple lexical substitutions.

```
-Derivative(Product(0.398942280401433*exp(-0.5*log(-mx + Dummy_39[i])**2/sx**2) /
   (sx*Dummy_39[i]), (i, 1, n)), mx)/ 
Product(0.398942280401433*exp(-0.5*log(-mx + Dummy_39[i])**2/sx**2) /
   (sx*Dummy_39[i]), (i, 1, n)))
```

===

With JohanC's changes https://stackoverflow.com/a/66070692/901925 :

```
In [182]: deriv
Out[182]: 
 n - 1                 
  ____                 
  ╲                    
   ╲   log(-mx + x[i]) 
    ╲  ────────────────
-   ╱    2             
   ╱   sx ⋅(-mx + x[i])
  ╱                    
  ‾‾‾‾                 
 i = 0                 

In [183]: fx = lambdify([x, mx, sx, n], deriv)
     ...: 

In [184]: fx??
Signature: fx(Dummy_2642, mx, sx, n)
Docstring:
Created with lambdify. Signature:

func(x, mx, sx, n)

Expression:

-Sum(log(-mx + x[i])/(sx**2*(-mx + x[i])), (i, 0, n - 1))

Source code:

def _lambdifygenerated(Dummy_2642, mx, sx, n):
    return (-(builtins.sum(log(-mx + Dummy_2642[i])/(sx**2*(-mx + Dummy_2642[i])) for i in range(0, n - 1+1))))
```

===

As per JohanC's comment, the function could (should?) be rewritten as

```
def foo(x, mx, sx, n):
    return -np.sum(np.log(-mx + x)/(sx**2*(-mx + x)))
```

For a small sample:

```
In [206]: test
Out[206]: 
array([2.32179572, 3.46861414, 6.46627075, 2.70090544, 2.45496557,
       2.63163795, 2.94254768, 2.7017532 , 2.47925472, 2.30607048])

In [207]: fx(test,2,1,len(test))
Out[207]: 11.862478799879577

In [208]: foo(test,2,1,len(test))
Out[208]: 11.862478799879577
```

Clearly `lambdify` does not have enough "knowledge" of `numpy` to replace the `sum('comprehension')` with the "vectorized" solution.

But we can use our own knowledge to generate values for individual `x[i]`, here replace by a generic `y` symbol:

```
In [224]: pdfy = 1 / (y * sx * sqrt(2 * pi)) * exp(-S.Half * ((log(y - mx)) ** 2 / (sx) ** 2))

In [225]: f1 = diff(log(pdfy), mx)    
In [226]: fx1 = lambdify([y, mx,sx], f1)

In [227]: fx1?
Signature: fx1(y, mx, sx)
Docstring:
Created with lambdify. Signature:

func(y, mx, sx)

Expression:

log(-mx + y)/(sx**2*(-mx + y))

Source code:

def _lambdifygenerated(y, mx, sx):
    return (log(-mx + y)/(sx**2*(-mx + y)))

In [228]: fx1(test, 2, 1)
Out[228]: 
array([-3.52347235,  0.26168834,  0.33507905, -0.50703316, -1.73097394,
       -0.72737698, -0.06277536, -0.50469809, -1.53472262, -3.86819368])

In [229]: -fx1(test, 2, 1).sum()
Out[229]: 11.862478799879577
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to signify that the sum isn't calculated as a numpy sum. So, it could be slow for large arrays. I suppose there is no way to force lambdify to create a numpy array and sum?  (By the way, I just found out that `expand_log(..., force=True)` creates a sum.)

Comment: I explored moving the `sum` out of the `lambdify`, that is, get a function that can generate values for each of the `test` elements, and sum at the end.